# How to detect pin state change in pulled up pins

Tags: ground, pullup

I am working on Toradex module and developing a simple application where I am detecting the input and displaying it on UART. Now the application requirement is that we give 12v as input but the processor pin cannot take 12v as input so I am using below circuit to convert it to 3.3v using `PC817` Optocoupler. The below circuit is working fine.

(3.3v and GND on the transistor side of `PC817` is from the processor side and 12v supply is from the power supply side, to provide isolation)

[image]

Now there are few pins in the processor which are pulled up. That means they are by default high and giving 3.3v. Now to detect input on these pins I need to pull them down. That means I'll have to connect them to ground to detect change in the pin state. So I'll have to design the circuit in which if I give 12v as input, those pins go down. So what circuit should I make for pulled up pins to detect input change.

Comment: Are you required to use an optocoupler for this? Because with the same ground on both sides of the optocoupler you are not using it for isolation. You are paying the high cost of an optocoupler when you could probably use a $0.07 transistor instead.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am not using the same ground. Those 3.3v and gnd on the transistor side is from the processor. So it is isolated.

Comment: Eh, even if they were to use the same grounds it's probably still enough to prevent the 12V from touching the input pin.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, okay, but so is a mosfet and a protection diode. Still a lot cheaper than an opto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the emitter of the output side of the optocoupler to the ground of the processor, and the collector of the output side to the IO pin of the processor, then this should give you the behaviour you want.

When the transistor conducts, it will pull down that processor's internal pull-up resistor to down to a little bit above ground, but it should be low enough to register as a logic zero.  You can find the actual voltage in the datasheet as V_CE(SAT), which is around 0.2 volts for the PC817.

You will no longer have your own pulling resistor of your own at all, since the processor has one already.

What I had in mind was this:
[image: Schematic of proposed solution]

Comment: Thiis is a good first answer. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar should you wish to add a schematic diagram on this or any other post. It's worth spending 15 minutes exploring how it works. Double-click on a component to configure options.

Comment: Cool I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I could give you a complete answer but telling you what you should be doing will help you much more. You REALLY should be able to work that out yourself if you want to develop any understanding of what you are doing.  And, you are capable of doing so.

Consider

- The OC acts as an on off switch.
- R2 pulls the pin to the idle state.
- When on the OC pulls the pin to the required active state.
- The OC output needs to maintain correct polarity (ie most positive on collector, most negative on emitter).

Given the above you should trivially easily be able to rearrange the components that you have to do what you want.

Let us know what you come up with. We'll advise if it's less than ideal.

**_____________________________**

If the grounds are not identical then it's a good idea for them to have different symbol names. If you are using the schematic for PCB production then it's essential.